# Take a picture, choose between Full or Square Mode in camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way to use the overlays in the `UIImagePickerController` to show the square picture a user might use, while having a toggle button in there somewhere to switch on the fly?

Currently the iOS 7 camera has this capability, but `UIImagePickerController` does not (thanks Apple), so is there a way to add this functionality?

Would using `AVCaptureSession` be necessary? It seems like serious overkill, and I'd have to program flash/focus/etc all over again, I think.

Failing that, is there a customizable class that already exists that I could just implement?

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure out the best course of action here, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, if you would like to see `UIImagePickerController` support square image capture you should definitely file a feature request, as the more people who file feature requests the more visibility it can get.

Comment: @lxt I have indeed done this. I suspect it's unlikely Apple will enact the suggestion though, and I can't wait until they do. I really need help implementing this, and I'm still at a loss.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the camera view by transforming the scale

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.5);
imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = transform;
```

with the arguments being the scale to change the `x` and `y` axis of the camera screen by.  You could add a button that re-presents the camera view within the view controller at the top of your hierarchy.  It may not perfectly recapitulate the native phone app, but it will be a pretty good approximation.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this with a custom cameraOverlayView that letterboxes the viewfinder. Once the picture has been taken you'll have to crop the resulting image.

Comment: How would the code look? It would have to be viable for iOS 6 and 7, and the camera UI is different for both.